# PhpStorm with EasyPHP Devserver - PHP Warning: Failed loading Zend extension

Tags: easyphp-devserver

Getting the following error with PhpStorm (2022.1.2) with EasyPHP Devserver (17.0):

```
PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension '' (tried: E:\Projects\PHP Migration\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php7427vc15x86x220629181102\ext\ (The specified module could not be found.), E:\Projects\PHP Migration\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php7427vc15x86x220629181102\ext\php_.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Jun 30 16:23:02 2022] PHP 7.4.27 Development Server (http://localhost:8080) started
```

In the php.ini:

```
zend_extension = ""
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart = false
xdebug.dump_globals=1
xdebug.dump=COOKIE,FILES,GET,POST,REQUEST,SERVER,SESSION
xdebug.dump.SERVER=REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD,REQUEST_URI
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.show_mem_delta=1
xdebug.collect_includes=1
xdebug.collect_vars=1
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.collect_return=1
xdebug.auto_trace=0
xdebug.trace_options=0
xdebug.trace_format=0
xdebug.trace_output_dir="E:\Projects\PHP Migration\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\xdebug\trace"
xdebug.trace_output_name="trace.%t"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_append=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="E:\Projects\PHP Migration\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\xdebug\profiler"
xdebug.profiler_output_name="cachegrind.out.%s.%t"
```

I also have Xdebug Manager 1.7 enabled for EasyPHP Devserver.

**UPDATE** I have the above settings in the php.ini based on advice at:

https://github.com/CemDemirkartal/How-to-Install-Free-Extensions-for-EasyPHP-Devserver

In particular:

"zend_extension = "" will be created by EasyPHP directly. (Tested)"

So why I do I see this warning?

Comment: So what is your question? If the question is "why do I see this warning" then it's in your php.ini, first line: `zend_extension = ""` -- either remove it or specify what extension to load.

Comment: *"So why I do I see this warning?"* Because you have `zend_extension = ""` in your php.ini. You need to point to the actual Xdebug extension file here. This issue has nothing to do with PhpStorm. It's your PHP / EasyPHP. Perhaps it needs to do some extra step which has not been done yet.... I do not use EasyPHP so cannot advise on this moment.

Comment: **BTW** -- the Xdebug settings in your php.ini -- they are for Xdebug v2 that is no longer supported (for maybe like 2 years now). And Xdebug v3 uses different parameter names, so if you actually got Xdebug v3 there, then make sure to check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: Ah, yep I'm using v3.  I'll update the php.ini.  Thanks